# Create a database then table with dockerfile

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm using Postgres and looking to create a database and then table after the container is created. Right now I using a dockerfile and init.sql file. The database gets created but the table gets created in the default postgres database. How do I get my new database to be the default one or at least get my table created in the correct database? Thank you

```
Dockerfile
FROM library/postgres
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

init.sql
CREATE DATABASE myApp;
CREATE TABLE session(sessionguid UUID NOT NULL, created text NOT NULL, sessionlife integer NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a set of variables that control things like the name of the user an the name of the database that is automatically created. Here is the relevant piece of [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) (see `Environment Variables` section):

> POSTGRES_DB
>
> This optional environment variable can be used to define a
>   different name for the default database that is created when the image
>   is first started. If it is not specified, then the value of
>   POSTGRES_USER will be used

Just specify it as environment variable in `run` command or in `Dockerfile`:

```
ENV POSTGRES_DB myApp
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Roman Konoval you can use `POSTGRES_DB` env variable to create the database.

Here is the relevant piece of documentation (see Environment Variables section):

> POSTGRES_DB
>
> This optional environment variable can be used to define a different name for the default database that is created when the image is first started. If it is not specified, then the value of POSTGRES_USER will be used

Then to create a table or do any sql imports (extend postgres image: https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/postgres/#how-to-extend-this-image).

Your `dockerfile` should look like this:

```
FROM library/postgres
COPY start.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/start.sh
```

---

`start.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
psql -h localhost -U user -W -d database_name -f /path/to/init.sql
```

when you run your container, you need to mount your sql script to `/path/to/init.sql` as follows:

```
$ docker run my_postgress_image -e "POSTGRES_DB=database_name" -v ./init.sql:/path/to/init.sql
```